# Upload Images by Front end Users in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, image-gallery, joomla2.5

I need allow registered front end users to add, remove images to image gallery. i'm using `SIGE - Simple Image Gallery Extended` which can found in http://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/sige-simple-image-gallery-extended for my image gallery.

how could i allow registered front end users to add, remove images to image gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to do this seeing as you are using a plugin, will take a long time, with a lot of trial and error. Will be 10 times easier to use a gallery component such as the ones shown below:

[Phoca Gallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery/3150)

[JoomGallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery/5481)

more gallery extensions can be found [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery)